# How Can I Use Class Fields with Parcel Bundler?

Tags: javascript, es6-class, parceljs

I'm receiving error "`Missing class properties transform.`" when I use use public ES6 Class field declarations.  How can I modify my Parcel settings to allow this?

## Current Code

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <div id="greeting"></div>
  <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
class Greeter {
  greeting = 'Hello';

  constructor(container, name) {
    container.innerText = `${this.greeting} ${name}`;
  }
}

new Greeter(document.querySelector('#greeting'), 'Justin');
```

## Workaround

I can only get this to work if I remove the `greeting = 'Hello';` declaration:

```
class Greeter {

  constructor(container, name) {
    this.greeting = 'Hello';
    container.innerText = `${this.greeting} ${name}`;
  }
}

new Greeter(document.querySelector('#greeting'), 'Justin');
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Field_declarations

Comment: @LawrenceCherone My browser [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Browser_compatibility) is not an issue.  Do you have a solution using Babel and Parcel?

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to file `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

See [@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties](http://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) for more details.  You should be able to use public, static, and the new [private fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Private_fields) too.